# org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, threadpool, hikaricp

Below is my `hikariCP configuration` :

```
spring.datasource.hikari.connection-timeout=10000

spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10

spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=15

spring.datasource.hikari.pool-name=HikariConnectionPool
```

---

While testing with JMeter, when I hit `500 threads` I got following exception for some of the transactions.

```
org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
```

Comment: It seems that you haved reached maximum load.what's your question exactly?

Comment: how can i configure hikaricp so that it can handle any number of threads at a time?

Comment: You will always reach a limit, isn't 500 threads at the same time sufficient enough? you can show your code also,maybe there's a leak or wrong implementation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks ,I have change connection-timeout From 10 sec to 100 sec It Solved my issue.